# ** exception error: undefined function eredis:start_link/0

Tags: module, include, erlang

I'm trying to include the [eredis](https://github.com/wooga/eredis) in my Erlang project to connect to redis. I put it in a lib/ directory, and used `-include_lib ("../lib/eredis/include/eredis.hrl").` It compiles fine in `erl`, but then trying to create a client fails with `** exception error: undefined function eredis:start_link/0`.

redis_worker.erl:

```
-module (redis_worker).
-export ([get/2, set/3, client/0]).
-include_lib ("../lib/eredis/include/eredis.hrl").

client() ->
  eredis:start_link().

get(Client, Key) when is_list(Key) ->
  {ok, Val} = eredis:q(Client,["GET", Key]),
  io:format("Got key: ~s which had value ~s~n", [Key, Val]).

set(Client, Key, Value) when is_list(Key) andalso is_list(Value)->
  {ok, <<"OK">>} = eredis:q(Client, ["SET", Key, Value]),
  io:format("Set key: ~s to ~s~n",[Key, Value]).
```

Why does it compile fine (which I'm assuming means executing the `include_lib`) but blow up when I try to use included libraries?

Comment: Have you compiled eredis? Do you have the eredis/ebin directory in your load path? Compiling and loading are different operations with different paths. Using ERL_LIBS env variable can make it easier to load modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

include_lib has always been a source of minor confusion. include_lib's behavior is almost identical to include, but shouldn't point to a filepath. In include_lib, the first path component is assumed to be the name of an application.

For example

`-include_lib("../lib/eredis/include/eredis.hrl").`

Will use code:lib_dir(lib) to find the directory of the current (latest) version of lib, and then the subdirectory include is searched for the file eredis/include/eredis.hrl (ignoring pattern substitution).

It's worth noting that the generally preferred strategy in Erlang for dependencies is to use  rebar and compile and pass the appropriate dependency path in via `-pa`. However, in your sans rebar setup, that would mean passing `-pa ../lib/eredis/include/eredis.hrl` to erl directly after compiling. `-pa` will include that directory to your code path.

Comment: I have used rebar to create an app but am just trying to test things out. Right now I have to just manually compile each file I need in `erl` which is such a pain. So with rebar what should this look like?

Comment: It's quite simple! Try something like this https://gist.github.com/3602558 and then you don't need to "include" anything, you can just reference the module eredis directly.

Comment: Amazing! So I am guessing I should delete lib haha